# What do Square Brackets Mean in This Informix Query?

Tags: informix

I am converting some informix SQL to SQL Server.

What do the square brackets mean in the query below?

```
SELECT unique cl_name[1,5] FROM client
```

cl_name is a varchar field.

Comment: More information at manual : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1439.htm?lang=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Informix-specific syntax for substrings.  The equivalent in SQL Server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(cl_name, 5)
FROM client
```

Comment: Although your answer helps it does not solve the question what does it mean. It only gave a comparision.